# PlayerJoinEvent - Create a welcome message Spigot 1.12.2 (Java)

Tags: java, minecraft

I don't understand why he always returns to me "You never played" then the first time ok, but the second I don't understand

I'm trying to make a condition:
If the player has already played I do nothing: no message the player receives nothing!
If the player has never played : Welcome message + He receives an item + and I get his position to explode fireworks
And I would have liked to add a counter of players who join in the second condition

> ```
> Commands Class:
> ```

```
package fr.antyss77.pandowelcome;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class Commands implements Listener {
    private Main main;


    @EventHandler
    public void PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        Location loc = player.getLocation();

        boolean hasPlayed = player.hasPlayedBefore();

        if (hasPlayed != true) {
            player.sendMessage("You've already played !");
        } else {
            player.sendMessage("You never played !");
            player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.SAND, 12));
            loc.getWorld().spawnEntity(loc, EntityType.SPLASH_POTION);

        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> Main class:
> ```

```
    package fr.antyss77.pandowelcome;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    private String color(String arg) {
        return ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', arg);
    }

    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(color("&6[&ePandoWelcomer&6] &ehas just started."));
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Commands(), this);
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(color("&6[&cPandoWelcomer&6] &ehas been shut down."));
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me understand my mistake I will be infinitely grateful, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (hasPlayed != true)` should be `if (hasPlayed == true)` as you have it doing the opposite of what you want.

Your code would look like:

```java
package fr.antyss77.pandowelcome;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class Commands implements Listener {
    private Main main;


    @EventHandler
    public void PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        Location loc = player.getLocation();

        boolean hasPlayed = player.hasPlayedBefore();

        if (hasPlayed == true) {
            player.sendMessage("You've already played !");
        } else {
            player.sendMessage("You never played !");
            player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.SAND, 12));
            loc.getWorld().spawnEntity(loc, EntityType.SPLASH_POTION);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this way the problem is that it does this: https://i.imgur.com/3xwUqyv.png
It's all "You never played" that comes out

Comment: I have tried different things since but unfortunately still no results

Comment: @Mojito991 is your server cracked/in offline mode?

Comment: My server is local and only accepts premium versions

Comment: @Mojito991 try debugging with `System.out.print(player.hasPlayedBefore() + "Played before");`

Comment: First connection: https://i.imgur.com/jyq4HsU.png
and this is valid for the second connection :/

Comment: Second try with == verification :
https://i.imgur.com/eiEk63y.png

Comment: Then it works @Mojito991 , it will be `true` if you played the server before

Comment: But after each restart/reload it is supposed to tell me that I never played, right?

Comment: No @Mojito991, `hasPlayedBefore` has it's own storage. If you want to check if a player has joined the server that session, create a `List` or a `Map` then add to it everytime a player joins. Then check if they exist in that if you want it like that after a restart

Comment: Oh yes, I understand better, and what do you think would be better between a map and a list please? In terms of performance, because if we imagine 1000 people are in this list it could be complicated, right? And then with the list do I have to do a database storage? Or will only the list/map be enough to store the data?

Comment: @Mojito991 You won't need a database if you are only after storing the players joining after a restart. A `List` would be more performant than a `Map`.

Comment: I was told that when I asked for advice https://i.imgur.com/oIwiKT9.png so if this is the case it could be extremely painful to manage it would mean that at each restart/reload it would be set to 0

Comment: Yes @Mojito991 that is what you are after based on what you have told me

Comment: I just want the data to be saved after a restart, a reload, so the List is not the best solution, do you agree?

Comment: @Mojito991 then you use `player.hasPlayedBefore();`, simple as that. hasPlayedBefore already has a file system database